# Setting breakpoints in a Razor file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I am trying to set breakpoints in my razor (.cshtml) file, but every time I try, it says the breakpoint could not be ser, or else I get the following error message:

The following breakpoint could not be set:
...
The Common Language Runtime was unable to set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 5):

I found that in my web.config, I had the following line:

```
<compilation 
    debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"
    assemblyPostProcessorType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspPerformanceInstrumenter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

The assemblyPostProcessorType attribute was causing the problem.  I'm assuming it does something to the dynamically-generated razor assemblies that breaks debugging.

So I simply removed that attribute to get:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```